# Problema al mostrar un panel y ocultar otro

Tags: c#

Estoy creando un formulario y estoy usando un `tabControl`, dentro de un `tabPage`. Estoy usando varios paneles, mis paneles abarcan todo el espacio, por lo tanto, están encimados. Yo los mando a llamar de esta manera:

```
private void salud_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Salu.Visible = true;
    Economico.Visible = false;
}
```

El problema es que cuando yo oprimo el primer botón me aparece su panel, pero al oprimir otro botón ya no aparece su respectivo panel.

Comment: mm si, hasta el momento agregue controles en mi tabpage que funcionan como un menu, agregue un panel1 encima de mi tabpage y agregue mas controles, al llamarlo por visible= true, si funciona. Pero agregue un panel2 encima de mi panel1 y este panel 2 al llamarlo desde un boton de mi TabPage ya no aparece solo funciona el primer Panel1. Ay Dios, no se si me di a entender..

Comment: private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Economico.Visible = true;
            Salu.Visible = false;
           
           

        }

Comment: Oh vale si solo estoy usando por el momento esos dos paneles,

Comment: Estas usando Windows Forms?

Comment: Si, eso es lo que estoy usando

Comment: Si vas a llamar a otro panel, por ejemplo el de salud, solo configura `Salu.Visible = true;` y nunca los ajustes a `false`, seguro es un bug, no entiendo por que pasa.

Comment: mm ya habia intentado eso, y al final sale a razon de lo mismo :c, pero bueno gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Yo no pude, pero espera un rato a ver si alguien mas entiende tu problema :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que aunque no te lo parezca, el segundo `Panel` sea "hijo" del primero, y por eso al ocultar el primero el segundo permanece oculto. Para solucionarlo, intenta hacer algo asi en el constructor de tu formulario:

```
 public Form4()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     Salu.Parent = this.tabControl1.TabPages[0];
     Economico.Parent = this.tabControl1.TabPages[0];
 }
```

Obviamente tendrás que cambiar `this.tabControl1.TabPages[0]` dependiendo del nombre de tu `TabControl` y del indice del `TabPage` donde se encuentren.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el primer panel es `Salu` y el que está por encima es `Economico`, con un botón para mostrar cada uno de ellos, con esto debería de funcionar:

```
private void BtnVerPanelSalu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
   Economico.Hide();
}
private void btnVerEconomico_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Economico.Show();
}
```

... o también:

```
private void BtnVerPanelSalu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Economico.Visible = false;
}
private void btnVerEconomico_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Economico.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Genial! muchas gracias me funciono lo de hide :)